# Ionic alert display error if passwords don't match

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and I'd like to use the Ionic alert to change a password for a user.
At the moment I got this:

```
let alert: Alert = Alert.create({
  title: 'Forgot Password',
  subTitle: 'Enter a new password',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'password',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'New Password'
    },
    {
      name: 'confirm_password',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Password'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Change Password',
      handler: data => {
        if (data.password != data.confirm_password) {
          return false;
        } else {
            ...some requests sent...
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Now, if I type 2 different passwords, the alert isn't dismissed, but I'd like to display a message on the alert.

Can this be done with Ionic Alert? I didn't manage to find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using $ionicPopup which is meant for user input. It takes in a scope so that you can do the angular you're looking for. Unfortunately, you cannot programmatically disable the save button if the passwords don't match.

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="password" ng-model="data.password">' +
              '<input type="password" ng-model="data.confirm_password">' +
              '<div ng-show="data.password!=data.confirm_password>Passwords do not match</div>'
    title: 'Forgot Password',
    subTitle: 'Enter a new password',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: 'Save',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {
          if (data.password != data.confirm_password) {
            return false;
          } else {
            ...some requests sent...
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```